# Remover com php linha no mysql

Tags: php

tenho esta função para enviar o array para o ficheiro com o php:

```
function deletar(){
    var ids = []; //arraypara armazenar os id's a serem deletados
    $(".colorir").each(function(){ //percorre todos os tr que possui a classe colorir
        ids.push($(this).find(".apagar").attr("Id")); //adiciona o id da linha ao array
        $(this).remove();
    })

    $.ajax({
        url: './deleteRAD',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {ids:ids},
        error: function(){

        },
        success: function(result)
        { 
        }
    });
    //só fazer a chamada para remoção das linhas no php
    console.log(ids);
}
```

O valor do `ids` enviado pelo `ajax` é `["33,Rute"]`.

Depois no ficheiro do `php` faço o `delete`:

```
$partes = explode(',',$_POST["ids"]);

$partes1 = $partes[0];
$partes2 = $partes[1];

$delete = "DELETE FROM centrodb.Alertas WHERE Id='$partes1'";
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $delete);
if (false === $result) { echo mysqli_error(); }
```

Mas não remove na base de dados e no ficheiro log do servidor web recebo a seguinte mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu `$_POST['ids']` é um array onde cada item dele é parecido com a string `'33,Rute'`, pelo que parece você quer fazer um `explode` em um item dele ou seja o código correto seria:

```
$partes = explode(',', $_POST['ids'][0])
//                                   ^
//                                   índice do item
```

Imaginando que você vai passar mais dados nesse array talvez você vai precisar *iterar* entre eles, para isso você pode usar `for`,`foreach`,...  Ou seja algo como no exemplo abaixo.

```
if( isset($_POST['ids']) && is_array($_POST['ids']) )
{

    foreach( $_POST['ids'] as $valor )
    {

        $partes = explode(',',$valor);

        print_r($partes);   /// para você testar
        #$partes1 = $partes[0]; 
        #$partes2 = $partes[1];

        #$delete = "DELETE FROM centrodb.Alertas WHERE Id='$partes1'";
        #$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $delete);
        #if (false === $result) { echo mysqli_error(); }

    }
}
```

<sup>O código acima não foi testado.</sup>